# Как получиться id пользователя?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграмм бота на c#, как реализовать:

```
message.from_user.id
```

из Python на c#?

Comment: У вас ведь есть наверно IDE, которая подсказывает что можно, а что нельзя, вот что мешает нажать точку и посмотреть все доступные методы и свойства? Поймете тогда, что будет там наверно что-то по типу `message.From.Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update.Message.Chat.Id;
```

содержит идентификатор чата. Может быть это то что надо?

Comment: Как минимум я посмотрел свой Id через своего бота и Id который можно посмотреть в Track24.ru например и они совпали, следственно, это как я понимаю внутренний телеграмовский Id

Comment: Т.е. Chat id это id не чата получается, а пользователя?